# Error with commiting in sourcetree for bitbucket in windows

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am a new user of bitbucket(I want to be). I have created the repository, and I have configured sourcetree. However, when I want to commit the the files, I get an error as:

```
 git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false commit -q -F      
 C:\Users\Amir_HO\AppData\Local\Temp\uupm1wem.ugf

 *** Please tell me who you are.

Run


 git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
 git config --global user.name "Your Name"

 to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Amir_HO@AmiR.(none)')
```

Answer (score 0):

easy, just go to the source of tree options, then advanced options Take away the check mark and enter a name and email, then you give ready ok and everything worked well.